# replace one class in bean property list in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, broadleaf-commerce

I am working in broadleaf which is based on spring-mvc.

there are 3-4 blCustomPersistenceHandlers bean definition in different xml file based on project module.

```
<bean id="blCustomPersistenceHandlers" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean" scope="prototype">
        <property name="sourceList">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.admin.server.service.handler.CategoryCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.admin.server.service.handler.CustomerPasswordCustomPersistenceHandler"/>                
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.security.handler.AdminUserCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.admin.server.service.handler.CustomerCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.admin.server.service.handler.ProductCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.admin.server.service.handler.ChildCategoriesCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.admin.server.service.handler.SkuCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

below in different xml files

```
<bean id="blCustomPersistenceHandlers" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean" scope="prototype">
        <property name="sourceList">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.cms.admin.server.handler.PageTemplateCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.cms.admin.server.handler.StructuredContentTypeCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.cms.admin.server.handler.SandBoxItemCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.cms.admin.server.handler.PendingSandBoxItemCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.cms.admin.server.handler.TimeDTOCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.cms.admin.server.handler.RequestDTOCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.cms.admin.server.handler.StructuredContentItemCriteriaCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
                <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.cms.admin.server.handler.PageItemCriteriaCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Above definitions reside into jar files that we included.
Now i want to replace one of this handler , for example ProductCustomPersistenceHandler,

I need to change some functionality regarding that handler, so I changed that handler as below in my xml file.

```
<bean id="org.broadleafcommerce.admin.server.service.handler.ProductCustomPersistenceHandler"
        class="com.mycompany.server.service.handler.HCProductCustomPersistenceHandler" />
```

and also put bean defination into xml files

```
<bean id="blCustomPersistenceHandlers" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean"> <!-- scope="prototype" -->
        <property name="sourceList">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.mycompany.server.service.handler.HCProductCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
            </list>
        </property> 
    </bean>
```

ProductCustomPersistenceHandler class

```
public class ProductCustomPersistenceHandler extends CustomPersistenceHandlerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "blCatalogService")
    protected CatalogService catalogService;

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ProductCustomPersistenceHandler.class);

    @Override
    public Boolean canHandleAdd(PersistencePackage persistencePackage) {
        String ceilingEntityFullyQualifiedClassname = persistencePackage.getCeilingEntityFullyQualifiedClassname();
        String[] customCriteria = persistencePackage.getCustomCriteria();
        return !ArrayUtils.isEmpty(customCriteria) && "productDirectEdit".equals(customCriteria[0]) && Product.class.getName().equals(ceilingEntityFullyQualifiedClassname);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean canHandleUpdate(PersistencePackage persistencePackage) {
        return canHandleAdd(persistencePackage);
    }

    @Override
    public Entity add(PersistencePackage persistencePackage, DynamicEntityDao dynamicEntityDao, RecordHelper helper) throws ServiceException {
        Entity entity  = persistencePackage.getEntity();
        try {
            PersistencePerspective persistencePerspective = persistencePackage.getPersistencePerspective();
            Product adminInstance = (Product) Class.forName(entity.getType()[0]).newInstance();
            Map<String, FieldMetadata> adminProperties = helper.getSimpleMergedProperties(Product.class.getName(), persistencePerspective);
            adminInstance = (Product) helper.createPopulatedInstance(adminInstance, entity, adminProperties, false);

            adminInstance = (Product) dynamicEntityDao.merge(adminInstance);

            CategoryProductXref categoryXref = new CategoryProductXrefImpl();
            categoryXref.setCategory(adminInstance.getDefaultCategory());
            categoryXref.setProduct(adminInstance);
            if (adminInstance.getDefaultCategory() != null && !adminInstance.getAllParentCategoryXrefs().contains(categoryXref)) {
                categoryXref = (CategoryProductXref) dynamicEntityDao.merge(categoryXref);
                adminInstance.getAllParentCategoryXrefs().add(categoryXref);
            }

            //Since none of the Sku fields are required, it's possible that the user did not fill out
            //any Sku fields, and thus a Sku would not be created. Product still needs a default Sku so instantiate one
            if (adminInstance.getDefaultSku() == null) {
                Sku newSku = catalogService.createSku();
                adminInstance.setDefaultSku(newSku);
                adminInstance = (Product) dynamicEntityDao.merge(adminInstance);
            }

            //also set the default product for the Sku
            adminInstance.getDefaultSku().setDefaultProduct(adminInstance);
            dynamicEntityDao.merge(adminInstance.getDefaultSku());

            return helper.getRecord(adminProperties, adminInstance, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to add entity for " + entity.getType()[0], e);
            throw new ServiceException("Unable to add entity for " + entity.getType()[0], e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Entity update(PersistencePackage persistencePackage, DynamicEntityDao dynamicEntityDao, RecordHelper helper) throws ServiceException {
        Entity entity = persistencePackage.getEntity();
        try {
            PersistencePerspective persistencePerspective = persistencePackage.getPersistencePerspective();
            Map<String, FieldMetadata> adminProperties = helper.getSimpleMergedProperties(Product.class.getName(), persistencePerspective);
            Object primaryKey = helper.getPrimaryKey(entity, adminProperties);
            Product adminInstance = (Product) dynamicEntityDao.retrieve(Class.forName(entity.getType()[0]), primaryKey);
            adminInstance = (Product) helper.createPopulatedInstance(adminInstance, entity, adminProperties, false);

            adminInstance = (Product) dynamicEntityDao.merge(adminInstance);

            CategoryProductXref categoryXref = new CategoryProductXrefImpl();
            categoryXref.setCategory(adminInstance.getDefaultCategory());
            categoryXref.setProduct(adminInstance);
            if (adminInstance.getDefaultCategory() != null && !adminInstance.getAllParentCategoryXrefs().contains(categoryXref)) {
                adminInstance.getAllParentCategoryXrefs().add(categoryXref);
            }

            return helper.getRecord(adminProperties, adminInstance, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to update entity for " + entity.getType()[0], e);
            throw new ServiceException("Unable to update entity for " + entity.getType()[0], e);
        }
    }
}
```

I just extend this handler and make my new handler , as it runs only core handler is executing, I want to execute my handler.

But this is not working.
I can't change into core part, so I just need to replace handler with my handler.
How can I do that?
Is that possible in spring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For custom persistence handlers specifically, you can remove the core handlers by using the blCustomPersistenceHandlerFilters bean. So in your case you would define your beans like this:

```
<bean id="blCustomPersistenceHandlerFilters" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean" scope="prototype">
    <property name="sourceList">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.service.handler.DefaultCustomPersistenceHandlerFilter">
                <property name="filterCustomPersistenceHandlerClassnames">
                    <list>
                        <value>org.broadleafcommerce.admin.server.service.handler.ProductCustomPersistenceHandler</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then you can add your own CPH to the list like you were doing before:

```
<bean id="blCustomPersistenceHandlers" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean"> <!-- scope="prototype" -->
    <property name="sourceList">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.mycompany.server.service.handler.HCProductCustomPersistenceHandler"/>
        </list>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

And now the BLC Product custom persistence handler will not run but yours will.

This is probably a little too complex for your simple purposes of wanting to replace the out-of-the-box one with your custom one. It's possible that there is a good reason why we did it like this, but I added a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/issues/91) for it to investigate further.